# Multiprocessing, instance creation, and passing of function instances

Tags: python, class, multiprocessing

I need to run a bunch of hybrid stochastic/ deterministic simulations of reaction networks with the algorithms stated in `class Markov`. Id like to do so in parallel, and write all output to a single file, that is easy to use in further analysis. For now im storing it in npz files. When creating an instance of `Markov` in a slave process the error I get is: `global name 'Markov' is not defined`. So question is: how can I make an instance of `Markov` in my slave processes? Even more (general) questions are stated below the code.

```
import numpy as np
import pathos.multiprocessing as mp


class Markov(object):
    def __init__(self,SRN_name,rates,stoich_mat):
         self.S=stoich_mat
         self.SRN_name=SRN_name #SRN = Stochastic Reaction Network
         self.rates=rates
         self.nr_reactions=rates.shape[1]

def worker(SRN_name,rates,stoich_mat,init_state,tf,species_continuous):
    result = []
    try:
        sim=Markov(SRN_name=SRN_name,rates=rates,stoich_mat=stoich_mat)
    except Exception as e:
        print e

    result=None #here some methods of sim are executed

    return result

def handle_output(result):
    data=np.load("niks.npz").files
    data.append(result)
    np.savez("niks",data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    def sinput(t,amplitude=6.0,period=0.05,offset=1.0):
        return amplitude*np.sin(period*t)+amplitude+offset
    phospho_cascade=np.array(
                           [[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], # input
                            [-1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])# A

    phospho_rates=np.array([(0.2,0),2.0],dtype=object,ndmin=2)

    phspho_init=np.array([sinput,5.0],ndmin=2).T

    tf=1.0
    S_C=[0]

    np.savez("niks",stoich_mat=phospho_cascade,rates=phospho_rates,init_state=phspho_init)
    kwargs={"SRN_name":"niks","rates":phospho_rates,"stoich_mat":phospho_cascade,"init_state":rates,"tf":tf,"species_continuous":S_C}
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=mp.cpu_count())
    for i in range(2):
        pool.apply_async(worker,kwds=kwargs,callback=handle_output)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just to answer the second part of your question, yes, there are much easier ways to do multiprocessing. I would recommend trying your code again, but using the "threading" module. An example of threading looks like this:

```
import threading

#Just define any functions you'd like to thread:
def RandomFunction():
    print('Hello World')

#Now create the thread(s) as so:
threadName = threading.Thread(target = RandomFunction , args = () )

#Now start the threads. You may also use threadName.join(), if you'd like to wait for a thread to complete, before continuing.
threadName.start()
```

Using that same syntax, you can create threads for as many functions as you want, and run them simultaneously. And trust me, it's much much easier! :)

Comment: Hey, Id rather use multiprocessing since Threading is limited by the GIL.